# If you invest $\$1500$ at $7\%$ compounded annually, how many years would it take for your investment to grow

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

If you invest $\$1500$ at $7\%$ compounded annually, how many years would it take for your investment to grow to $3750$?

Is this right?

$$\text{term } = \frac{\log( \text{overall gain factor})}{ \log (\text{annual gain} ) }= 
\frac{ \log (3750/1500)}{ \log (1 + .07) }= \frac{\log (2.38)}{ \log (1.07) }= 12.816\text{ years}$$

Comment: There is a typo it should be $3750$ in place $3570$, resulting in $13.5428471089$

Comment: so what is the correct answer?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=3570%2F150&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&aq=f&oq=3570%2F150&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j61l2.1817&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#client=ubuntu&hs=xPD&hl=en&channel=cs&sclient=psy-ab&q=log+(3750%2F1500)%2Flog+(1%2B.07)&oq=log+(3750%2F1500)%2Flog+(1%2B.07)&gs_l=serp.3...59537.67843.2.68106.11.11.0.0.0.2.525.3208.0j3j3j3j1j1.11.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.Qdw2lP7zHno&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.bmk&fp=6e95ad80cbb19e1e&biw=1104&bih=619

Answer (score 1):

When one does mathematics, it can be  useful to go back to basic principles.

With interest rate of $0.07$, that is, $7\%$, compounded annually, in $n$ years $A$ dollars grow to 
$$A(1.07)^n$$
dollars. In our case, $1500$ grew to $3750$ in an unknown number $n$ of years, so
$$3750=1500(1.07)^n.$$
It follows that
$$(1.07)^n=\frac{3750}{1500}=2.5.$$
Take the logarithm of both sides, using your favourite base. We get
$$n\log(1.07)=\log(2.5),$$
and therefore
$$n=\frac{\log(2.5)}{\log(1.07)}.$$

**Remark:** Your procedure was correct. There was a little numerical slip in calculating $\frac{3750}{1500}$.

Comment: so answer is 13.54 ? correct

Comment: Yes, to $2$ decimal places it is correct.

Comment: Is this really the place for primary school maths?

Comment: @wolfies: It is useful mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

This is good, subject to revising your typo.  You have after $n$ periods that your balance is 
$$1500* 1.07^n.$$
Now set $$1500*1.07^n = 3750.$$
Begin by dividing to get
$$1.07^n = 2.5 $$
so
$$n = {\log(2.5)\over \log(1.07)} = 13.54.$$
Your answer is off a bit because you transposed two digits.

Answer (score 1):

If by chance you didn't want to use logarithm's you could make a table and write the formula out for the desired years:

$a(1+r)^n$

where $a$ is the initial amount, $r$ is the rate and $n$ is the number of years.

For year 12: $1500(1+0.07)^{12}$ = 3378.29

For year 13: $1500(1+0.07)^{13}$ = 3614.77

For year 14: $1500(1+0.07)^{14}$ = 3867.29

So if the desired final amount was 3750, it would take 14 years assuming we didn't want half years.

Assuming we did, simply play guess and check until we get a closer result.

$1500(1+0.07)^{13.5429}$ = 3750.01

And so on.